# How to write a Windows batch file that updates all file names in a folder by a numeric value?

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I have a folder "C:\Pictures\test" which contains about 200 photos and nothing else. (Actually, until I get this code working, it contains only 2 photos.) The photos are different file types (.png, .jpg, etc) and their names are all numbers. I'd like to add a fixed number to those file names, e.g. "4500.png" -> "4700.png" and "4501.jpg" -> "4701.jpg". I expect this situation to recur so I'd really like to automate it. Therefore, a few hours ago, I learned Windows batch files exist. Please be gentle -- I barely even know how to ask about the things I don't understand. (Two hours of googling preceded this question. Some of it was even helpful.)

By cobbling together code found elsewhere, I've written this code (note that I don't really care about catching any exceptions):

```
::renames all files in a folder by adding a fixed value

@ECHO OFF
SET /p addnum="Enter number to add to all photo names: "
SET /p loc="Enter folder location to navigate to: "

CD %loc%

FOR /F %%i IN ("*.*") DO (SET newname = SET /a %%i+%addnum% & SET file_name = %newname%)

PAUSE
```

Everything through the `CD` works. But the `FOR` statement line doesn't (small wonder -- this is the only part of the code I didn't copy from somewhere!). When I run it, it doesn't complain, but it doesn't do anything either -- no output; no change in the file names.

What I want the `DO` statement to do:

- define a variable `newname` which is the file name `%%i` (remember, this is a number) + `addnum`
- set the file name `%%i` to `<newname>.<extension>`

How should I actually write this batch file?

Comment: I suggest to use a GUI application for renaming files if you are not familiar with batch file coding. For example, the free (for private usage) multimedia viewer __IrfanView__ has in menu __File__ the menu item __Batch Conversion/Rename__ to rename files with an automatically incremented number. Or use the shareware file manager __Total Commander__ with its built-in __Multi-Rename Tool__ in menu __Files__ (Ctrl+M after selecting the files for example with Ctrl+A or Num++).

Comment: If you want to try to do it with a batch file, the obvious method would be to determine the highest number first, and begin with incrementing that one, otherwise you could end up with name conflicts. The oher thing you should do is to use a parsing method which reads all the filenames before performing the `do` portion. This way, your newly renamed files will not be reparsed in by the `command`/`set` and be processed in a never ending cycle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following batch file could be used which has only a rudimentary error handling.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "addnum=100"
set "loc=."
set /P "addnum=Enter number to add to all photo names: "
set /P "loc=Enter folder location to navigate to: "
pushd "%loc%"
if errorlevel 1 goto EndBatch
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.jpg *.png /A-D /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "^[0123456789][0123456789]*\.jpg$ ^[0123456789][0123456789]*\.png$"') do (
    set /A NewName=%%~nI + addnum
    ren "%%I" "!NewName!%%~xI"
)
endlocal
popd
:EndBatch
endlocal
pause
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `cd /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`